# Polyline to raster cell size too small to run?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arccatalog, raster-conversion

I'm trying to run a polyline to raster tool and would like the cell size of the outputted raster to match my DEM grid cell size of 1/3(0.0000925925926 degrees) or 1 arc second (0.000277778 degrees).

However the tool is taking forever to run on ArcMap, or fails to run on ArcCatalog.

Is the pixel size just too small for ArcGIS to convert, or is there another way I can achieve this?

I'd like to avoid aggregating the DEM grid.

Comment: What coordinate system is your polyline feature class in currently? It's not too small for geographic data but if your data is projected it's definitely too small. Have you set your environments cellsize, extent, output coordinate system and snapraster to your existing DEM?

Comment: @MichaelStimson Turns out the polyline was projected in meters, so I was trying to convert it to a cell size of 0.0002... meters. However after projecting the polyline to the DEM, the spatial reference of the polyline is still in meters?

Comment: It must be 'unknown' spatial reference so that ArcGIS can't work out how to transform the coordinates, define the projection of the polyline feature class to what it is using define projection tool http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000077000000 and have a read of snap raster http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001w0000000m000000 etc.. it will save you a lot of pain later.